Total area under multiple overlapping polygons
I have shape files from multiple years (eight total years) representing insecticide treatments over an area of land. I can easily find the total area treated, and compare overlap among two individual years. However, I'm stuck in developing a concise code to determine the total area treated two times, three times, for times, etc.
Simplified image attached as an example, each year is a different colour. Some of the area is only treated once (single colour), some is treated twice (overlapping colours) and some is treated 2+ times.
How do I go about finding the total area treated 1, 2, 3, 4, (etc.) times?

I cannot create example code like the map image (or share my shape files). However, here is a very simplified example of area treated per year with some overlap among years (as requested):
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

polygon1 <- st_polygon(list(
  matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
))

polygon2 <- st_polygon(list(
  matrix(c(2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
))

polygon3 <- st_polygon(list(
  matrix(c(0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.3, 0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 0.5), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
))

polygon4 <- st_polygon(list(
  matrix(c(2, 0.5, 2.5, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2, 2.5, 2, 0.5), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
))

polygon5 <- st_polygon(list(
  matrix(c(1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 1.5, 1.8, 1.8, 1.2, 1.8, 1.2, 1.5), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
))

polygon6 <- st_polygon(list(
  matrix(c(0.8, 0.8, 2.2, 0.8, 2.2, 1.2, 0.8, 1.2, 0.8, 0.8), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
))

polygon7 <- st_polygon(list(
  matrix(c(1.3, 2.2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.1, 2.8, 1.3, 2.8, 1.3, 2.2), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
))


year1 <- st_multipolygon(list(polygon1, polygon2)) |> 
  st_sfc()

year2 <- st_multipolygon(list(polygon3, polygon4, polygon5))|> 
  st_sfc()

year3 <- st_multipolygon(list(polygon6, polygon7))|> 
  st_sfc()


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = year1, fill = "#009E73", color = 'black', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_sf(data = year2, fill = "#E69F00", color = 'black', alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_sf(data = year3, fill = "#0072B2", color = 'black', alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_classic()


How would could I determine the total area covered three times, the total area covered only twice and the total area covered only once.

If you haven't loaded them into R,, what are the names of your shapefiles? If you have loaded them into R, are they sf objects and what did you name them?

You could take two different approaches: (A) recursively intersecting treatment polygons or (B) rasterizing polygons and using raster calculations. (A) offers "infinite" precision while (B) is quite straight forward and can be much faster, depending on shapes. Looks like most of your data is gridded anyway. Which approach would tackle the issue better?

@LTyrone the shape files are loaded into R, they are class 'sf' and 'data.frame', with geometry: 'sfc_MULTIPOLYGON. I don't see how what I've decided to call each shape file in the R environment is revenant. I have named each imported shape file in reference to the year it refers to (e.g. treatment_1990, treatment_1991, etc.)

@I_O the shape files are large and the polygons are complex. The image of the map was generated from a subset of my data, the simple plot with rectangles was added as another user recommended I added code to illustrate my problem - in order to do that I needed to simplify things). How would I go about rasterizing polygons to determine the total area covered three times, the total area covered only twice and the total area covered only once.

The names of your files is relevant as a recursive approach may be an appropriate solution. Knowing the names helps to create a definitive answer.

Given you are interested in calculating the total area covered, it will useful know both the CRS and total extent of all your sf objects. To get the total extent coordinates, rbind() your sf objects, then run st_bbox().

using the raster approach and your example data:

gather the various simple features into one spatial dataframe (could be done manually of course):

library(sf)


    the_polygons <- 
      do.call(rbind,
              lapply(list('year1', 'year2', 'year3'),
                  FUN = \(o_name) data.frame(year = o_name,
                                             geometry = get(o_name)
                                             )
                  )
      ) |>
      st_sf()

## > the_polygons
## Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
## Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
## Dimension:     XY
## Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
## CRS:           NA
##    year                       geometry
## 1 year1 MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 1 0, 1...
## 2 year2 MULTIPOLYGON (((0.5 0.5, 1....
## 3 year3 MULTIPOLYGON (((0.8 0.8, 2....


create a base raster with the overall extent of the polygons (obtained with st_bbox and desired resolution. This empty base raster is later populated with the polygon values.

    library(terra) ## the workhorse for raster, as {sf} is for features

    raster_base <- the_polygons |> st_bbox() |> ext() |> rast(resolution = .1)



create the output raster by rasterizeing the polygons into the base raster, suming the count of non-empty values (one per polygon covering the particular cell):


    raster_output <- rasterize(the_polygons, raster_base, fun = sum)



extract and tabulate the cell values:


    table(values(raster_output))

##   1   2   3 
## 325  78   7

(multiply cell count by cell size to obtain area at your resolution)

visual control:

    plot(raster_output)




For a vector based method I would approach this by combining the data for all years into a single layer with variable that identifies the year, then perform a self intersection. That will produce an index that can be used to reference back to the combined year layer to get the details of each overlap, which you can combine in to a new field that lists the years.  This can then be consolidated by summarizing the resulting sf layer on your variables of interest. With really large layers the intersection step can take a while.
#assign a value to each year

year1 <- st_multipolygon(list(polygon1, polygon2)) %>%
  st_sfc() %>%
    st_union() %>%
      st_as_sf() %>%
        mutate(Year=2024)%>%
  st_set_geometry("geometry")
  

year2 <- st_multipolygon(list(polygon3, polygon4, polygon5))%>%
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_union() %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(Year=2023)%>%
  st_set_geometry("geometry")

year3 <- st_multipolygon(list(polygon6, polygon7))%>%
  st_sfc() %>%
  st_union() %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(Year=2022) %>%
    st_set_geometry("geometry")




###combine into a single layer
combo_years <- bind_rows(list(year1, year2, year3)) 


#self intersect, give an index of overlaps "origins"
combo_years_intersect <- st_intersection(combo_years)

#use the index nubers to the get the year values from the original data set and concantenate into a list using purr functions, could alos use an apply or loop to do the same
combo_years_intersect_list <- combo_years_intersect %>%
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON") %>%  #this not necessary in simplified example but in messy shapes sometimes linestrings an points created
  mutate(Year_List=map_chr(origins, \(x) paste0(combo_years$Year[x], collapse = "; ") ))



#group and summarise by the nuber of overlaps and the the overalpping years
combo_years_intersect_summarised <- combo_years_intersect_list %>%group_by(n.overlaps, Year_List) %>%
  summarise() %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(area=st_area(.))




mapview::mapview(combo_years_intersect_summarised, zcol="n.overlaps")



mapview::mapview(combo_years_intersect_summarised, zcol="Year_List")



##can be piped together   



combo_years_summary_piped <- combo_years %>%
  st_intersection() %>%
  mutate(Year_List=map_chr(origins, \(x) paste0(combo_years$Year[x], collapse = "; ") ))%>%
  group_by(n.overlaps, Year_List) %>%
  summarise()%>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(area=st_area(.))



##can calc other values at same time


combo_years_summary_many <- combo_years %>%
  st_intersection() %>%
  mutate(Year_List=map_chr(origins, \(x) paste0(combo_years$Year[x], collapse = "; ") ), 
         Year_Min=map_dbl(origins, \(x) min(combo_years$Year[x], na.rm=T) ),
         Year_Max=map_dbl(origins, \(x) min(combo_years$Year[x], na.rm=T) ))%>%
  group_by(n.overlaps, Year_List,Year_Min, Year_Max) %>%
  summarise()%>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(area=st_area(.))




mapview::mapview(combo_years_summary_many, zcol="n.overlaps")




mapview::mapview(combo_years_summary_many, zcol="Year_Min")
  


##can now summarise total area by overlapping treatments 



OVERLAP_SUMMARY_AREAS <- combo_years_summary_many %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
    group_by(n.overlaps) %>%
      summarise(total_area=sum(area))

#or

OVERLAP_SUMMARY_AREAS <- combo_years_summary_many %>%
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  group_by(Year_List) %>%
  summarise(total_area=sum(area))


With terra you can do that like this
library(terra)
v <- vect(c(year1, year2, year3))
crs(v) <- "local"

x <- terra::union(v)
x$n <- rowSums(values(x))
x$area <- expanse(x, transform=FALSE)
tapply(x$area, x$n, sum)
#   1    2    3 
#3.25 0.78 0.07 

And see
plot(x, "n")

(If you can avoid it, you really should not use a raster approach for a problem like this).
